# Problem with Paid Contract

Tags: ios, applications, app-store-connect

I signed up for a developer account for my son under my name because he is not of age yet and because he wants to make his own apps. But itunesconnect won't let me input my bank account info, ect. for the paid contract necessary for him to set up the iap because I already put in my own information for my own account. What should I do?

Comment: Call Apple and they will solve it for you, their online support (email, on-site etc) is way too slow and won't give you the right results.

Comment: @Robuust. Try not to answer a question in the comments.